# Expose Jenkins image on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-eks

i want to deploy Jenkins on EKS cluster and any one can access Jenkins url

i tried [this](https://devopscube.com/setup-jenkins-on-kubernetes-cluster/) and i change type: NodePort in  service.yaml to LoadBalancer
but DNS didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your worker nodes will have to have a public IP, which is a big security risk.

Better to create a Kubernetes service of type [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) which in your case will expose the Jenkins service in AWS.